# How do I use -Filter (with regex)?

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to write a script that deletes duplicate shortcuts from a desktop.
I'm trying to find the duplicates by filtering for *.lnk files that contain a number in brackets.

I've managed to make it work kinda but not as reliable as i want to.
I made it filter for names that contain brackets with any content like so:

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Desktop\*.lnk' -Filter "*(*)*"
```

This works but also includes brackets with characters or pretty much anything in them. How do I make the filter only look for brackets with numbers? e.g. (1), (232352),...

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Desktop\*.lnk' -Filter "*(\d+)*"
```

This is what I tried and it does not work for me.

Comment: Side note: your filter string is mixing wildcard and regular expression syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-3.0):

> **`-Filter`**
>
> Specifies a filter to qualify the Path parameter. The FileSystem provider is the only installed PowerShell provider that supports the use of filters. Filters are more efficient than other parameters, because the provider applies them when the cmdlet gets the objects rather than having PowerShell filter the objects after they are retrieved. The filter string is passed to the .NET API to enumerate files. That API only supports `*` and `?` wildcards.

The parameter `-Filter` supports only wildcard matches. If you need a regular expression match you need to do that with a subsequent `Where-Object` filter.

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Desktop\*.lnk' | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\(\d+\)' }
```

You can also pre-filter for filenames with parentheses with `Get-ChildItem`, and than limit the results to the desired subset with the `Where-Object` filter (which might provide better performance when you have to process a large number of files):

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Desktop\*.lnk' -Filter "*(*)*" |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '\(\d+\)' }
```

Comment: Documentation that they finally fixed.  They used to link to "about_wildcards" which included "[ ]" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-6 to explain -filter.